# grunt-package-modules cannot install dependency of itself

Tags: npm, gruntjs

I'm trying to use the npm package [grunt-package-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-package-modules) to gather my npm_module dependencies for a bundled deployment but ran into the error when running the command `grunt packageModules`:

`Fatal error: Refusing to install test as a dependency of itself`

This error typically occurs when the name of the project also appears in the list of dependencies in package.json as was the case [here](http://thisdavej.com/node-newbie-error-npm-refusing-to-install-package-as-a-dependency-of-itself/), but that does not occur in the original file or the one that is copied into the dist folder.

I was able to get this error with the simplest project setup I could create from the examples given in the grunt tutorial and the package wiki. Is there something I'm missing in setting up this plugin?

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-package-modules": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    packageModules: {
      dist: {
        src: 'package.json',
        dest: 'dist'
      },
    }
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-package-modules'); 
}
```

I'm on a PC and had the same thing happen on my home PC but had my co-worker run through this same setup on his mac and it worked successfully for him. Also tried updating node and npm since we had different versions with no luck.

Comment: I have built up the same stuff as you did and it runs fine. How do you call your task?

Comment: edited, just by calling `grunt packageModules`

Comment: Well, your setting is fine, though. Maybe [this](http://thisdavej.com/node-newbie-error-npm-refusing-to-install-package-as-a-dependency-of-itself/) helps.